# Removing element from wordreference API in PHP

Tags: php, html, api

How can I remove the elements I desire (for example, the search box) from by instructions in PHP?

*`Link :     http://api.wordreference.com/38159/enes/hello`*

*NOTE: in my site I first request what you see in the link above and paste it in a div, if this info is of any use*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For searching a HTML-tree for certain elements, which is what you seem to DOMXPath for searching the tree of an XML-tree.

Have a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php
Remember however that searching an XML tree is not the cheapest of operations, so use it with caution.

Writing XPath queries can be tricky - but Firebug can be used to easily form them ( in firebug, go to some element of desire and hover the "CSS path" firebug is showing - the tooltip contains the XPath for the same...)

Well, asuming that you for example want to get the content, try:
    $word = "hello";

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces.
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// preg_replace is used for security, all except a-z and 0-9, and underscore will be replaced with nothing.
$url = "http://api.wordreference.com/38159/enes/" . preg_replace( "/[^\w ]/", "", $word );

$doc -> Load( $url );

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// We start from the root element.
$entries = $xpath -> query( "//html/body/div/div[3]" );

// do some stuff with the elements found...
```

Comment: thank you a lot but I don't understand almost anything, not even where to start, I've just started coding, isn't there something simpler?